# TableAttribute is missing when change target from netcoreapp3.0 to netstandard2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I figured I should move my class libraries to use .net standard 2.1.

Is table attribute not in .net standard 2.1 ?

```
using PWDRS.Core.Entities.Base;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PWDRS.Core.Entities
{
    [Table("ReportType", Schema = "RF")]
    public class RfReportType : EntityBase
    {
        public RfReportType()
        {
        }
```

> The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'Schema' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TableAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/Schema/TableAttribute.cs) belongs to the *System.ComponentModel.Annotations* assembly, which [is not part](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/src/netstandard/ref) of the .NET Standard. And it seems there are no plans to include it, see  [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/450)

You need to install it as a package

```
Install-Package System.ComponentModel.Annotations -Version 4.6.0
```

or use *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore* package which includes *System.ComponentModel.Annotations*, if you need more

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.0.1
```

Comment: It is in the CORE project which is data base agnostic to I suppose the first option is best.. Or I could define the entity details in the context?  Trying to figure out which makes most sense

Comment: It depends ..., I would suggest the first one, but if you need other things related to EntityFrameworkCore in  CORE project then it doesn't make sense to have both packages, use only Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore